# Entity Framework sometimes doesn't load data

Tags: entity-framework, caching

In the following example

```
using (var context = new MyEntities() 
{       
   // Delete old data.
   foreach (var data obsoleteData)
   {
     context.DeleteObject(data);
   }

   // Create new data.
   var data = new DataEntity();

   // Initialize data
   // ...

   var id = FoundItem();
   var items = new List<MyItems>();
   foreach (var n in context.Sources)
   {
     var subItems = (from i in context.Entities1 
                     from g in i.Entity1Relations 
                     where g.Type == 0 && g.Id == id 
                     select i).ToList();

     Contract.Assert((from i in subItems 
             where i.SomeCount == 0 select i).FirstOrDefault() == null);
     items.add(FindSource(n, subItems);
   }

   foreach(var i1 in items)
   {
     data.SubItems.Add(i1);
   }

   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This asserts sometimes, but the database `SomeCount` is always > 0!

The `Entity1Relations` is a table that resolves m : n.

I assume that the entity framework doesn't queries the database everytime.

Is a solution for this problem available?

Comment: Can you post your model and describe what you are doing? E.g. what is `obsoleteData`, where does it come from? What do you do in the  `Initialize data` section? Apart from that, your naming conventions don't do much to help understanding (`Entities1`, `Entity1Relations`?).

Comment: This is a simplified example. I use a standard generated entities (from database generated in VS2010).

Comment: That's great. As I mentioned in my previous comment - it could help if you show your model and clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm try to delete an old data, and then fill the db with the the new created DataEntities. They will be filled from (by some id)  resolved items. Please  note, that the resolving bases on querying the relation table Entity1Relations. I asume that context.Entities1 uses in this case cached data instead of the real. How to ensure that the entity framework uses a new data?

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an error in FindSource that modified SomeCount Property of other objects. So it has nothing to do with EF.